# Change i3 Floating Window Order

Tags: i3

I'm using a terminal in floating window mode to keep the text of the terminal in the center of the display. The issue is that Deja Dup (a backup program) opens a floating window every day saying that the last backup was successful. I have to acknowledge that message in order for it to continue doing backups, but the Deja Dup floating window is opened behind my floating terminal, so I can't easily interact with it. Is it possible to change the default order of the floating windows?

Answer (score 0):

You can run commands when a window opens with `for_window`

Not sure if focus is enough but try:

```
for_window [class="deja..."] focus
```

You can get the class with `xprop -spy`, look for WM_CLASS.

https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#for_window